# Run-time exception in MIPS when trying to store register value in data segment

Tags: exception, assembly, mips

I am trying to write a program that takes in 2 inputs stores them inside registers and then stores those registers inside data segments.

```
.data
val1: .word 1
val2: .word 2
val3: .word 3

.asciiz "Branden"
.asciiz "Enter a number "
.asciiz "\n"

.globl main
.text

main:

addi $s0, $0, 23 # initializes the register $s0 to 23

lui $a0, 0x1001
ori $a0, $a0, 20 #outputs string that is at 20
ori $v0, $0, 4 #command for output
syscall
addi $v0, $0, 5 # asks for input
syscall 
addi $s1, $v0, 0 # set the value of $s1 as the given input


lui $a0, 0x1001 
ori $a0, $a0, 20 #outputs string that is at 20
ori $v0, $0, 4 #command for output 
syscall
addi $v0, $0, 5 #asks for input
syscall
addi $s2, $v0, 0 # set the value of $s2 as the given input

sw $s1, 0($t0) # store the value of $s1 into data segment val1
sw $s2, 4($t0) # store the value of $s2 into data segment val2


ori $v0, $0, 10 
syscall
```

The problem is I am getting this error: **error in C:\Users\Danny\MIPS\assignment1.asm line 34: Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: address out of range 0x00000000**

The error is occuring on the line sw $s1, 0($t0) but for what reason? does there need to be a lw associated with sw?

Comment: What is in the t0 register when it crashes?  I don't see you setting it, so presumably 0?  Probably not the right answer.

Comment: so what is the correct format to store it into val1? should i use lw to store val1 into $t0? @DavidWohlferd

Comment: I notice you're doing a bunch of `lui, ori` sequences. Can you use pseudo ops (e.g. `la`, `li`)? Also, you're hardwiring offsets to your `.asciiz` strings. Each one should have its own label. For example, if we change `.asciiz "Branden"` to `.asciiz "brandenfam"`, your print string syscall will break.

Comment: no I cannot use la or li unfortunately @CraigEstey

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned, you weren't setting `$t0` to anything, so it *was* zero for the `sw`

But, even if you wanted to use the construct, how would you get address? `la` makes this easy.

I've fixed the bug and recoded to use some pseudo-ops that make life easier [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
val1:       .word       1
val2:       .word       2
val3:       .word       3

me:     .asciiz     "Branden"
enter:  .asciiz     "Enter a number "
nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

    .globl  main
    .text

main:
    li      $s0,23                  # initializes the register $s0 to 23

    la      $a0,enter               # address of string to output
    li      $v0,4                   # print string syscall number
    syscall

    li      $v0,5                   # asks for input
    syscall
    move    $s1,$v0                 # set the value of $s1 as the given input

    la      $a0,enter               # address of string to output
    li      $v0,4                   # print string syscall number
    syscall

    li      $v0,5                   # asks for input
    syscall
    move    $s2,$v0                 # set the value of $s2 as the given input

    sw      $s1,val1                # store the value of $s1 into val1
    sw      $s2,val2                # store the value of $s2 into val2

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

    # NOTE: these are alternate ways to do the stores (they're after the exit
    # so they won't be executed)
    la      $t0,val1                # address of val1
    sw      $s1,0($t0)              # store the value of $s1 into val1

    la      $t0,val2                # address of val2
    sw      $s2,0($t0)              # store the value of $s1 into val2
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I am not allowed to use la or li but I did not know that I could directly use val1 with sw so that is helpful, thank you!

I did that deliberately to show one form.

But, when using `sw` in this way, it is actually a pseudo-op. Take a look at the sequence and you'll see that the `sw` generates `lui $at,...` and then `sw $s1,0($at)`.

The thing about pseudo ops is that they do something that the base instructions can't. Loosely [using some C-like syntax], `la $t0,val1` generates `lui $at,(&val1 >> 16)` and then `ori $at,$at,(&val1 & 0xFFFF)`

So, you might be able to code the `la` by hand. But, [AFAIK], there isn't a way to specify/split the "upper/lower" of a symbol the way a pseudo op can.

Comment: I am not allowed to use la or li but I did not know that I could directly use val1 with sw so that is helpful, thank you!